# InitialContext factory error

Tags: java, oracle, datasource, jndi

I am studying [Managing database connections with JDBC](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jdbc/section5.html) published by IBM. It is some old stuff (2001). They are using JNDI. When I tried to implement their code:

```
 try {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(
        Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");

        // Create the initial context

        Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

        // Here we create the actual DataSource and then set the relevant 
        // parameters.

        TdsDataSource ds = new TdsDataSource();

        ds.setServerName(serverName);
        ds.setPortNumber(portNumber);
        ds.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
        ds.setUser(login);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setDescription("JDBC DataSource Connection");

        // Now we bind the DataSource object to the name we selected earlier.

        ctx.bind(filePath, ds);
        ctx.close();

    // Generic Exception handler, in practice, this would be replaced by an 
    // appropriate Exception handling hierarchy.

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

But I found out that there is no "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory" file system service provider. Then I changed the code as follows (from [Initialize Data Source Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm)).

```
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setDriverType("oci");
ods.setServerName("dlsun999");
ods.setNetworkProtocol("tcp");
ods.setDatabaseName("816");
ods.setPortNumber(1521);
ods.setUser("scott");
ods.setPassword("tiger");
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.bind("jdbc/sampledb", ods);
```

When I tried to execute this code, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

I think it is still asking for the Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY. Any solutions ? I am searching for it from morning.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include the below lines before creating `InitialContext` object.. It should fix the problem.

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");
```

This basically tells the `System` which initial context library you are using to store your datasource contexts.

Comment: That won't work either. It is saying jdbc (in "jdbc/sampledb") is not in the context.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you can post StactTrace or any details about container/server you are running this code in.

The DataSource object and the JNDI Context are two different resources, though they are used together. `JNDI` is a repository that can hold objects identified by a path like names. `DataSource` is an object that contains info for establising database connection using JDBC. To provide system wide access to a DataSource, its object will be bind to JNDI with a key, so that it can be lookup globally within the system.

Seems like your issue is with JNDI provider library. You do not need to change the DataSource implementation library (from `TdsDataSource` to `OracleDataSource`) for this.

May be this detail can help you or post more details to understand your runtime environment.